# $_SESSION variable does not persist when using onClick="location='index.php'"

Tags: php, session, onclick

I can get my session variable to persist from page to page, but when I click my HOME button (code below), then the session variable is empty when I echo it out back on the index.php page.

```
<input type=button name="home" value="Home" onClick="parent.location='index.php'">
```

I am using

```
$g_puser = $_SESSION['puser'];

$_SESSION['puser'] = $g_puser;
```

on each page in an attempt to persist the variable.  I have a submit button that goes to another page using the php `header('Location: newpage.php')`, and that persists, but the home button using the onclick redirection does not.  Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example which demonstrates the problem?  It could be as simple as you forgetting to start the session on the page in question.

Comment: Replace your button onclick : `onClick="parent.location='index.php'"` To: `onClick="document.location.href='index.php'"` and see.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing my HOME button to this code:

```
<input type=button name="home" value="Home" onClick="parent.location='index.php?puser=<?php echo $g_puser ?>'">
```

and then on the index.php page, I used $_GET to retrieve the puser variable and store it back in the session variable.

```
$s = $_GET['puser'];
$_SESSION['puser'] = $s;
```

Thanks.